# Is it possible to run an "If" statement within another "If" statement?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a script that will check to see if folder `X` exists and then check to see if folder `Y` doesn't exist before executing code.

Essentially here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
If "X" folder exists Then
  If "Y" folder doesn't exist Then
    Create "Y" folder
    Create Message box
    Run "Z" CMD file
IF "X" folder doesn't exist Then
  Create "Y" folder
If both "X" and "Y" folder exist then 
  Do Nothing
End IF
```

**Note:** The problem I'm having is that I can get it to do a variation of 2 of the 3 `If` statements, but never all 3 to work as desired. Here is the script I'm currently using. I've tried using `Else`/`ElseIf` as well and just can't seem to get them working. Here is the script I'm currently using:

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
vAPPDATA = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not objFSO.FolderExists(vAPPDATA & "\Mozilla\Firefox") Then
    objFSO.CreateFolder(vAPPDATA & "\Mozilla\Update1")
    End If
If objFSO.FolderExists(vAPPDATA & "\Mozilla\Firefox") Then
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(vAPPDATA & "\Mozilla\Update1") Then
        objFSO.CreateFolder(vAPPDATA & "\Mozilla\Update1")
        x=msgbox("Firefox has been updated and will need to close and reopen to import your profile." ,0, "Firefox Has Been Updated!")
        Dim objShell
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objshell.run (VAPPDATA & "\test.cmd")
        End If
    If objFSO.FolderExists(vAPPDATA & "\Mozilla\Update1") Then
        End If
    End IF
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VBScript supports nesting conditionals. However, your logic seems incomplete (and unnecessarily convoluted) to me. Your second "outer" condition

```
IF "X" folder doesn't exist Then
```

makes creation of folder `Y` depend only on the fact that `X` doesn't exist, which is a given at this point in your code, because the first condition (`"X" folder exists`) evaluated to `False`. Checking if `Y` doesn't exist would make more sense at that point:

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FolderExists("X") Then
  If Not fso.FolderExists("Y") Then
    fso.CreateFolder "Y"
    MsgBox ...
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Z"
  End If
ElseIf Not fso.FolderExists("Y") Then
  fso.CreateFolder "Y"
End If
```

"Do nothing" is the implicit default when there is no `Else` branch and the given conditions aren't met, so you don't need explicit code for that.

With that said, you could simplify your code by switching the conditions, since both main branches create `Y` if the folder doesn't exist, but execute other code only if `X` does exist:

```vb
If Not fso.FolderExists("Y") Then
  fso.CreateFolder "Y"
  If fso.FolderExists("X") Then
    MsgBox ...
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Z"
  End If
End If
```